# Show new data in real time

Tags: chart.js

With this script I cannot automatically update new data.

For now I have all the data displayed.

```
var ' . $var1 . ' = [];
        var ' . $var2 . ' = [];             

        const ctx = $("#myChart");
        
        const data = {
            labels: '.$var1.',
            datasets: [{
                label: "Student Marks",
                data: '.$var2.',
                backgroundColor: "#0156AC",
                pointStyle: "circle",
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHoverRadius: 10
            }]
        };
        const config = {
            type: "line",
            data: data
        };
        const myChart = new Chart (
            ctx,
            config
        );
                
        var getData = function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "' . $url . '",
                    success: function(data) {
                        
                        
                     for(var i in data) {
                   '.$var1.'.push(data[i].'.$var1.');
                    '.$var2.'.push(data[i].'.$var2.');


                }

                         
                        
                    }
                });
        
        };
        
        setInterval(getData, 1000);
```

I can't display the new data
I followed different videos but I can't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are missing at the point where you process newly available data.

1. You also need to add new values to `data.labels`.
2. At the end you need to invoke `myChart.update()`.

> For further information, please take a look at [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-charts) from the `Chart.js` documentation.